# Replace or Disable null-value in Datagrid in a formsapplication

Tags: .net, datagrid, null

I'm working on a formsapplication with a datagrid in it.
How can I disable or replace (null)-values in cells when im databinding the grid to a database.
When I am in the Designer view and clicking on the little arrow on the grid,I only see the option "Autoformat"

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- To alter your database query to return your null columns with properly values
- To alter your grid to test if your value is null and deal with it
- To implement `DataGrid.ItemDataBound` event and treat your null values there

Depending on your framework version, you could to use [null coalescing operator](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/20/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq.aspx), `??` like:

```
string test1 = "123" ?? "no value"; // will have "123";
string test2 = null  ?? "no value"; // will have "no value";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that doing a simple boolean check on an object at query time would allow for you to filter nulls.  Or in the actual query: not null

http://www.windows-tech.info/15/8234081daef047ee.php

Comment: No I dont want to eliminate records with null values in some columns, I just want to  display it properly in my datagrid. By replacing (null) into "" for example

Comment: well than the other suggestion would be to see if the object that you query back == null or object.myField == null.